# SQL WHERE/AND error when using it multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I've started learning SQL on Friday. I'm using pgAdmin4

I'm having trouble with one line on this code:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, nationality, date_of_birth
FROM DIRECTORS
WHERE nationality IN ('French' , 'German', 'British');
AND date_of_birth BETWEEN 01/01/1940 AND 31/12/1969; // error
```

The first 3 lines work, they list everything as needed, the 4th line is giving me an error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AND"
> LINE 4: AND date_of_birth BETWEEN 01/01/1940 AND 31/12/1969;

On the fourth line I'm trying to check date_of_birth between =>01/01/1940 && <=31/12/1969.

I still get an error when I use `WHERE` instead of `AND` on the 4th line, I don't know what word to use (AND,WHERE,etc) when I am being asked to find more details in a database.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have added `;` after the `where` statement that means end of code block. Remove it and also put an inverted comma like this '01/01/1940' for the date value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your date in a `single quote` or `double qoute`. And use a proper date format `'yyyy-MM-dd'` and remove the first `;`.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, nationality, date_of_birth
FROM DIRECTORS
WHERE nationality IN ('French' , 'German', 'British')
AND date_of_birth BETWEEN '1940-01-01' AND '1969-12-31';
```

Answer (score 1):

the time style that mysql supports is yyyy-MM-dd( HH:mm:ss)
AND date_of_birth BETWEEN '1940-01-01' AND '1969-12-31';